# Delete freestyle after rendering

Tags: compositing-nodes, freestyle

In some cases I want to have the Ray Tracing-render and the Freestyle-render seperated, so I can post-process it in Photoshop. It seems to be that the Freestyle lines are placed onto the render after the Ray Tracing renderprocess. So my question is

Is it possible to delete Freestyle lines **after** rendering?

Comment: Use separate render layer. Set a material override for all objects to be white shadeless (for example) and enable freestyle for this layer.

Comment: As mentioned in https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/105536/29586 you can render just the freestyle lines on a render layer by disabling all the other elements (environment, surfaces, hair). You can then combine them in the compositor or manipulate as separate layers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing you have to do is enable freestyle and create a new render layer(I called it lines).  Next, you can delete the line set for the default RenderLayer and add one for the lines layer.

[image]

You can then enable transparency and(on the lines RenderLayer) disable use Environment, AO, Surfaces, and Hair.

[image]

If you render now it will render two RenderLayers, one with your scene and one with only the lines.  You can switch between them at the bottom of the UV/Image Editor(after it renders).  Then, if you then switch to the node editor and enter the compositor and check `Use Nodes`, you can duplicate the `Render Layers` node and set the duplicated one to the lines RenderLayer.  You can then connect both of their outputs to two file output nodes and select the output destination(Remember to give them names).  It will then output the lines and rendered image separately.

[image]

Comment: ... and, you might add:  if jspr selects  'OpenEXR MultiLayer' as their output format, and has installed a Multichannel EXR plug-in for their Photoshop, they won't need to go to the compositor to direct their file output.  The Blender [Render Layers and Passes] will automatically be saved as channels in  a single file per frame,  and can be imported to  Photoshop [Layer Groups and  Layers]  using the plug-in..